# Messages Error in Django doesn't appear to the user when registering

Tags: django, message, user-registration

I have a problem with my user registration function. My goal is to have the code check in the database to see if the username is already taken or not, and let the user know in case it's already taken. For now, the code is working fine for the first part, but the second doesn't work. The message "Something is wrong" appears but not the one specific to the username "This user already exists". I tried to do the following options that I found on stack, but nothing is working:

- first to change the form and raise a ValidationError and check for error in the front
- second to verify in the function "user_register" if the user is already taken and raise a message.error, this is the option in my code bellow ( I get an error here)
- third, try if the user exists and bring an error in the context

Would someone knows what is wrong with my code? It could be something really stupid.

Here is my view.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        group = Group.objects.get(name='Stroller') 
        group.user_set.add(user)
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "New account successfully created" )
        return redirect('accounts:dashboard')

    else:
        if User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username']).exists():
            messages.error(request, "This user already exists, please chose another name")
            return redirect('accounts:create_user')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Something went wrong - please check again the form")
            return redirect('accounts:create_user')

else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'dist/sign-up.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is my template

```
<h1 class=display-4>Sign Up</h1>
                    <hr>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="row mx-n2">
                        <form action="{% url 'accounts:create_user' %}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <p>Please, enter a valid username <br>{{ form.username }} <br><i>Usernames are unique on the platform</i></p>
                            <p>Please, enter a valid password <br>{{ form.password1 }}<br>
                                <i>Not too similar to your personal information</i><br>
                                <i>Not too common</i><br>
                                <i>At least 8 characters</i><br>
                                <i>Not only numbers</i>
                            </p>
                            <p>Please, enter the same password as before <br>{{ form.password2 }}<br></p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Done</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you not get an error here: `User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username']).exists()`? You are calling `exists` on a **model instance** (`.get()` will return a model instance) and not on a queryset. Furthermore why even use the message framework for this? The form already generates those errors for you (you can customize them by customizing form class), you shouldn't redirect to the same page instead you should just render the page again with the form with the errors. Show your template `dist/sign-up.html`...

Comment: Yes, I receive an error there, now I understand why - thank you. I tried using the error from the form, but then they don't appear on the front which is why I thought message was a good option

Comment: The errors from the form don't appear because you don't render the same submitted form back, instead you are redirecting if the form is invalid. Simply render the same template again with the invalid form and see that the errors will show up this time with the form.

Comment: It's working, thank you a lot!!